# ¿Cómo hacer un efecto de "dibujado" a un SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lo que quiero lograr es que se dibuje el SVG (se nota en el *snippet*), pero actualmente, tengo esto y lo que pasa es que se dibuja un *stroke* (línea sobresaliente), por lo que quedan dos figuras, lo que busco es que solo se dibuje la figura de la nube sin ningún *stroke*.

```css
.cloud {
     height: 145px;
     stroke-dasharray: 1000;
     stroke-width: 1px;
     fill: transparent;
     stroke: #000;
     animation: drawCloud 1s linear forwards;
}

 @keyframes drawCloud {
     0% {
         stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    }
     100% {
         stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

 body {
     background-color: #fff;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     height: 100vh;
     margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg class="cloud" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 122.88 79.13" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    <path d="M86.35,29.93c-0.75,0.37-1.51,0.78-2.26,1.21c-2.25,1.32-4.47,2.93-6.74,4.78l-4.84-5.54c1.67-1.55,3.48-2.96,5.4-4.21 c1.53-1,3.13-1.89,4.78-2.65c0.66-0.33,1.32-0.64,2-0.93c-3.19-5.65-7.78-9.7-12.98-12.2c-5.2-2.49-11.02-3.45-16.69-2.9 c-5.63,0.54-11.1,2.59-15.62,6.1c-5.23,4.05-9.2,10.11-10.73,18.14l-0.48,2.51l-2.5,0.44c-2.45,0.43-4.64,1.02-6.56,1.77 c-1.86,0.72-3.52,1.61-4.97,2.66c-1.16,0.84-2.16,1.78-3.01,2.8c-2.63,3.15-3.85,7.1-3.82,11.1c0.03,4.06,1.35,8.16,3.79,11.53 c0.91,1.25,1.96,2.4,3.16,3.4c1.22,1.01,2.59,1.85,4.13,2.48c1.53,0.63,3.22,1.08,5.09,1.34l72.55,0c3.53-0.85,6.65-2,9.3-3.48 c2.63-1.47,4.78-3.26,6.39-5.41c2.5-3.33,3.73-8.04,3.78-12.87c0.06-5.07-1.18-10.16-3.59-13.86c-0.69-1.07-1.45-2.03-2.25-2.89 c-3.61-3.89-8.19-5.59-12.95-5.62C93.3,27.6,89.73,28.43,86.35,29.93L86.35,29.93L86.35,29.93z M91.99,20.65 c1.6-0.25,3.2-0.38,4.79-0.36c6.72,0.05,13.2,2.45,18.3,7.95c1.07,1.15,2.08,2.45,3.03,3.9c3.2,4.92,4.84,11.49,4.77,17.92 c-0.07,6.31-1.77,12.59-5.25,17.21c-2.27,3.01-5.18,5.47-8.67,7.42c-3.36,1.88-7.28,3.31-11.68,4.33l-0.82,0.1l-73.08,0l-0.46-0.04 c-2.67-0.34-5.09-0.97-7.29-1.88c-2.27-0.94-4.28-2.15-6.05-3.63c-1.68-1.4-3.15-2.99-4.4-4.72C1.84,64.25,0.04,58.63,0,53.03 c-0.04-5.66,1.72-11.29,5.52-15.85c1.23-1.48,2.68-2.84,4.34-4.04c1.93-1.4,4.14-2.58,6.64-3.55c1.72-0.67,3.56-1.23,5.5-1.68 c2.2-8.74,6.89-15.47,12.92-20.14c5.64-4.37,12.43-6.92,19.42-7.59c6.96-0.67,14.12,0.51,20.55,3.6 C81.9,7.15,88.02,12.76,91.99,20.65L91.99,20.65L91.99,20.65z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Lo que he intentado es:

- Cambiar la propiedad `stroke-width` a `15px`, pero la figura se ve demasiado rara, es decir, el *stroke* se ve demasiado ancho. Se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la imagen esta compuesta por un `path` que dibuja la nube **"dos veces"**.

La solución más simple es remover "una nube" y acomodar las lineas.
Yo usé [esta herramienta](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/).

Después de eso, si, podes cambiar la propiedad `stroke-width`.

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.cloud {
     height: 145px;
     stroke-dasharray: 1000;
     stroke-width: 8px;
     fill: transparent;
     stroke: #000;
     animation: drawCloud 1s linear forwards;
}

 @keyframes drawCloud {
     0% {
         stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    }
     100% {
         stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

 body {
     background-color: #fff;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     height: 100vh;
     margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg class="cloud" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 122.88 79.13" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    <path d="M 86.35 29.93 C 85.6 30.3 84.84 30.71 84.09 31.14 C 81.84 32.46 79.62 34.07 77.35 35.92 C 84 31 85.8 30 88 29.25 C 81.5 16.94 76.91 12.89 71.71 10.39 C 66.51 7.9 60.69 6.94 55.02 7.49 C 49.39 8.03 43.92 10.08 39.4 13.59 C 34.17 17.64 30.2 23.7 28.67 31.73 L 28.19 34.24 L 25.69 34.68 C 23.24 35.11 21.05 35.7 19.13 36.45 C 17.27 37.17 15.61 38.06 14.16 39.11 C 13 39.95 12 40.89 11.15 41.91 C 8.52 45.06 7.3 49.01 7.33 53.01 C 7.36 57.07 8.68 61.17 11.12 64.54 C 12.03 65.79 13.08 66.94 14.28 67.94 C 15.5 68.95 16.87 69.79 18.41 70.42 c 1.53 0.63 3.22 1.08 5.09 1.34 l 72.55 0 c 3.53 -0.85 6.65 -2 9.3 -3.48 c 2.63 -1.47 4.78 -3.26 6.39 -5.41 c 2.5 -3.33 3.73 -8.04 3.78 -12.87 c 0.06 -5.07 -1.18 -10.16 -3.59 -13.86 c -0.69 -1.07 -1.45 -2.03 -2.25 -2.89 c -3.61 -3.89 -8.19 -5.59 -12.95 -5.62 C 93.3 27.6 89.73 28.43 86.35 29.93 L 86.35 29.93 L 86.35 29.93 z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

El stroke hace referencia a la línea exterior del dibujo, en contraposición al relleno. En tu caso, lo que pasa es que tu dibujo se compone de dos figuras, una exterior y otra interior. Si, por ejemplo, eliminamos la interior, quedaría así

```html
<svg class="cloud" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 122.88 79.13" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    <path d="M91.99,20.65 c1.6-0.25,3.2-0.38,4.79-0.36c6.72,0.05,13.2,2.45,18.3,7.95c1.07,1.15,2.08,2.45,3.03,3.9c3.2,4.92,4.84,11.49,4.77,17.92 c-0.07,6.31-1.77,12.59-5.25,17.21c-2.27,3.01-5.18,5.47-8.67,7.42c-3.36,1.88-7.28,3.31-11.68,4.33l-0.82,0.1l-73.08,0l-0.46-0.04 c-2.67-0.34-5.09-0.97-7.29-1.88c-2.27-0.94-4.28-2.15-6.05-3.63c-1.68-1.4-3.15-2.99-4.4-4.72C1.84,64.25,0.04,58.63,0,53.03 c-0.04-5.66,1.72-11.29,5.52-15.85c1.23-1.48,2.68-2.84,4.34-4.04c1.93-1.4,4.14-2.58,6.64-3.55c1.72-0.67,3.56-1.23,5.5-1.68 c2.2-8.74,6.89-15.47,12.92-20.14c5.64-4.37,12.43-6.92,19.42-7.59c6.96-0.67,14.12,0.51,20.55,3.6 C81.9,7.15,88.02,12.76,91.99,20.65L91.99,20.65L91.99,20.65z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Esto es, quitando la segunda figura que comienza en M91.99. dibujándose sólo la figura externa